# what is the best way to use @font-face for all browsers?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I wonder of how can i make @font-face work with all browser .I googled a lot before asking here and found lots of ways but nothing works fine with me.
Css code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'cblockbold';
    src: url('GE_SS_Two_Light.eot');
    src: url('GE_SS_Two_Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('GE_SS_Two_Light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('GE_SS_Two_Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('GE_SS_Two_Light.svg#CreativeBlockBBBold') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}

.navbar {
    height: 40px;
    font-family: cblockbold;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #00CCFF
}
```

and this my html code

```
<div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li class="item"><a href="#"><strong>الرئيسية</strong></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="#"><strong>تسوق الان</strong></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="#"><strong>خدماتنا</strong></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="#"><strong>من نحن</strong></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="#"><strong>تواصل معنا</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

sorry for my bad English

Comment: “Nothing works fine” is not a problem description. Please explain what happens. From the title of the question, it seems that you get the desired font in some browsers (which?) but not on others (which?). Or maybe the fonts don’t quite look what you wanted (how?). And the odds are that the (main) problem is not in the code posted but in the font files. Where did you get the font from, and how did you produce the different font formats? A live URL might help in analyzing what the problem really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this service and it has never failed me: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0):

You can use these sources to create web compliant fonts

- http://www.google.com/fonts/
- http://www.cufonfonts.com/
- http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator (thanks to Gabriel)